# Can I access Azure App Configuration inside a script called in a pipeline task?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/pull-key-value-devops-pipeline) I can make the variables available to the entire pipeline. However, if the following task is running a PowerShell script, called Script.ps1. Are the configs vars going to be available in that script or do I have to pass them as input to the script?

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking, including some code.

Comment: Are configurations pulled from App Configuration available to scripts ran from subsequent tasks? Not sure how much more clarification you need..

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/pull-key-value-devops-pipeline#use-key-values-in-subsequent-tasks) you provided answers your question as asked. If you're having some specific difficulty, you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: This is being used as inline script. I'm asking about using the variables in a file script. "Script.ps1".

Comment: There's no difference. An environment variable is an environment variable. You can easily test this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key-values that are fetched from App Configuration are set as pipeline variables, which are accessible as environment variables. To use environment variables in your PowerShell script file you can refer to the following.

Use environment variables in PowerShell script file:
[image]

Use PowerShell task in pipeline:

[image]

The result in the pipeline:

[image]